Blazor : calculate a value or leave as default
if I want to supply a calculated value to a component such as a grid or any parameter really, and if there is no value then I want to leave the value as it was since it is being automatically calculated by that component, such as a default col width.
Basically I want to say parameter = calculated value or if not found leave as it was, i'm struggling with having to provide a value in the 'or' case that is affecting the original defaulted value...like this:
Width="@dict.GetValueOrDefault(colWidth, "")"

If I provide the "" as the default then it overrides what the component was doing on its own.
Alternatively:
Width = valueFound ? value : 0;

The zero is now overriding the original value, and I don't have access to 'Width' since it is a parameter of a grid component, not something I can access if that makes sense.
I want to do this:
Width = valueFound ? value : "LEAVE WHATEVER WIDTH WAS ORIGINALLY";

TYIA
Actual example
<DxGrid Data="@data"
    @ref="Grid">
<Columns>
    @foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
    {
        <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="@data.colName"
                          Width="@valueFound ? value : **LEAVE WHATEVER WIDTH WAS ORIGINALLY**
        </DxGridDataColumn>                                
     }
</Columns>


An actual example might help?  What is Width?  Are we talking Css here?

conceptually, it is part of a grid component parameter, but question stands for any non-accessible parameter of a control/component... i will try to clarify the question with an edit

Reading from here https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxGridColumn.Width ... the "The column’s width" is null by default... so u can set it null... and that is it. Your Width problem is not here.... the parent or other components will cause it to change.

hmm, let me try giving it an actual null, i believe it threw an error

You're fighting the Razor syntax.  The other answer provided works for a single parameter, but if you have more than one it starts to get very messy.
You can revert to RenderTreeBuilder code which is what the Razor compiler actually produces.
@foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
{
    __builder.OpenComponent<DxGridDataColumn>(0);
    __builder.AddComponentParameter(1, "FieldName", data.colName);
    if (data.width is not null)
        __builder.AddComponentParameter(2, "Width", data.width);

    __builder.CloseComponent();
}

Or build a method;
    private RenderFragment<DataColumn> BuildGridColumn => col => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<DxGridDataColumn>(0);
        builder.AddComponentParameter(1, "FieldName", data.colName);
        if (data.width is not null)
            builder.AddComponentParameter(2, "Width", data.width);

        builder.CloseComponent();
    };

and then call it;
@foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
{
    @BuildGridColumn(col)
}


This is along the lines of the best I suppose could be done, i will mark as answer ty

What if u do like this?
<DxGrid Data="@data"      @ref="Grid">
  <Columns>
    @foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
    {
      @if (valueFound)
          {
           <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="@name"  Width="@value"> </DxGridDataColumn>                                
          }
          else
          {
            <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="@name"> </DxGridDataColumn>                                
          }
     }
   </Columns>


Yes, def a possibility i have already considered, i just am hoping there is a sleeker way with less code that i'm not aware of, thank you
